# Why isn't my list displaying in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

In Orchard 1.3.10 when I create a list it gets assigned a permalink such as /people. When I add a person to the list and go to /people the person does not display. I see

When I add a widget to display people the person displays.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this Orchard working as designed?

Using the shape tracing module I see this In my content zone:

```
<div class="zone zone-content">    <div class="content-control">
        <div class="manage-actions"><a href="/Admin/Contents/Edit/41?ReturnUrl=%2Fpeople">Edit</a></div>

<article class="content-item list">
    <header>

    </header>

</article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do the content items show correctly on the "Contained Items" page on the dashboard?

Comment: Yes, and if I click on an item, that item displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new site fixed my issue.

On my debug site I'm able to work around the issue by changing my list sort order, but not on my real site.

I filed a bug here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18421